# How does one author a portable container which behaves well with MSVC++'s checked iterators feature?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, containers

I'm defining a new type of container for various reasons. I would like to be mostly similar to `std::vector`'s interface; and it just so happens that for enumeration purposes I can leave `wchar_t *` and `wchar_t const*` as my `iterator` type and `const_iterator` type, respectively. (This container is a "view" on top of some other, larger, data structure that just happens to have a vector-compatible interface)

However, if I do this, users using MSVC++ are going to get crazy numbers of warnings from algorithms like `std::copy`, unless they define `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. This is a good thing -- [MSVC++'s checked iterators feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965.aspx) protects users from all kinds of bugs in debug mode. I would like to be compatible with this feature by implementing such checking features where required. This leaves a couple of questions:

1. VC's `stdext::checked_iterator` class accepts a container in its constructor. Is that container required to be one of the built in STL container types?
2. How can I disable checked iterators when [`_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh697468.aspx) is `0`?
3. How can I do this in such a way that the container is portable to other compilers which don't have checked iterators? (I would like to avoid implementing the whole thing twice if possible)

Boost solutions are okay.

Comment: GCC has a similar feature with [`_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt12ch30s04.html). But be careful with it - if a precompiled library attempts to use your containers or iterators built with `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`, then memory corruptions will occur. In one project, I had to abandon its use because of one dependency on Boost (`shared_ptr`).

Comment: @jww : you're right for the first part, but the second part makes no sense to me. shared_ptr is a header only library.

Comment: @v.oddou - `shared_ptr` is header only, but it has dependencies. Use `bcp` to copy `shared_ptr` and its dependencies to a different folder. There's something like 150 or 160 of them. Not all of them are header-only.

Comment: @jww : that must be a new record, last time I did try it was ~1000 files. designed my own shared_ptr lol.